# Django Multiselect, how to override choices properly

Tags: django, forms, overriding

this is my forms.py

```
CHOICES = []
class salDeptChartForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=2,label = 'Firma',help_text='A valid email address, please.')
    date_validfrom = forms.DateField(label = 'Bu Tarihten',required=False)
    date_validuntil = forms.DateField(label = 'Bu Tarihe Kadar',required=False)
    saldept = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label = 'Satış Departmanları',choices=CHOICES,    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

this is where I override the choices in my view.

```
    form = salDeptChartForm(initial={'company':'01'})
    saldeptlist = saleinstance.fetchSalDept()
    form.fields['saldept'].choices = saldeptlist <this is where I override>
```

problem occurs when I select one of the options. form doesnt get validate.

```
Select a valid choice. * is not one of the available choices.
```

I think, even I override the choices in my view django still checks with previous choices itially I created. I get the correct html output tough.

How to overcome this?
thx

complete view code is there.
form initiates twice one for get and one for post, I dont know if its best either.

```
def salDept(request):
    member_id = request.session['member_id']
    saleinstance = sale(member_id)
    chartinstance = charts(member_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = salDeptChartForm(initial={'company':'01'})  <first init>
        saldeptlist = saleinstance.fetchSalDept()  <its a list>
        form.fields['saldept'].choices = saldeptlist  <override choices>
        print 'get worked'
        return render(request, 'chart/sale/salDept.html',locals())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = salDeptChartForm(request.POST) <second init>
        print 'post worked'
        if form.is_valid(): <fails>
            print 'valid'
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            vfr = form.cleaned_data['date_validfrom']
            vun = form.cleaned_data['date_validuntil']
            validfrom = formatDate(vfr)
            validuntil = formatDate(vun)
            selectedSalDepts = request.POST.getlist('saldept')
        else:
            print 'not valid'
            print form.errors
        resultdict = chartinstance.salesBySaldept(company,selectedSalDepts,validfrom, validuntil)
        form = salDeptChartForm(initial={'company':company,'date_validfrom':request.POST['date_validfrom'], 'date_validuntil':request.POST['date_validuntil']})
        domcache = 'true'
        return render(request, 'chart/sale/salDept.html',locals())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation fails because you only overwrite the choices on the `GET` method. You don't do anything for the `POST`, so as far as Django knows, no choice is valid for the `POST`. Adding the choices to `POST` should fix your problem.

Comment: I dont like code repetition, so is there a way to achieve this with only one form initiation and one choice override?

Comment: Yes it is. It might require you to create some helper functions or you might consider to look into class based views. They would be perfect in a situation like this. This is good intro to them: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr9HOLipPXc

Answer (score 3):

Okay, you need override the **init**() of the form to do accomplish this.

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    email       = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
    users       = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in User.objects.all()]
)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['users'].choices = [(x, x) for x in User.objects.filter(name__contains='Patel')]


    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_datas
```

Here in line number (3) you can see that I have provided all the possible choices and then in the **init** I have filtered the choices, this is important because Django validates your submitted request from the former and displays the choices from the latter